# About the definition of hyperbolicity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definition, hyperbolic-equations

I have a doubt about hyperbolic PDE's. The classical LeVeque's book, Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws, give us:

***These notes concern the solution of hyperbolic systems of conservation laws. These are time-dependent systems of partial differential equations (usually nonlinear) with a particularly simple structure. In one space dimension the equations take the form
$$\partial_t u+\partial_x f(u)=0$$
with $f'(u)$ diagonalizable, with real eingenvalues.*** (c.f. pages 1-2)

Well, many other locals has the following definition. Suppose the PDE

$$a(x_{1},x_{2}){\frac {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial x_{1}^{2}}}+b(x_{1},x_{2}){\frac {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial x_{1}\partial x_{2}}}+c(x_{1},x_{2}){\frac {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial x_{2}^{2}}}+d(x_{1},x_{2}){\frac {\partial u}{\partial x_{1}}}+e(x_{1},x_{2}){\frac {\partial u}{\partial x_{2}}}+f(x_{1},x_{2})u=g(x_{1},x_{2})$$

If $b^2-4ac<0$, the PDE is elliptic.

If $b^2-4ac=0$, the PDE is parabolic.

If $b^2-4ac>0$, the PDE is hyperbolic.

However, the equation from LeVeque has $b=a=c=0$, so it would be parabolical...

Are there two kinds of hyperbolicity?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there is only one type of hyperbolicity. When you hear of _first_ order systems of hyperbolic equations, it is usually meant in the sense that the equations in the system generate hyperbolic equation(s). For example, consider $$u_{t} = v_{x}, v_{t} = u_{x}$$ which you can clearly tell is a wave equation ($u_{tt} = u_{xx} \implies b^{2} - 4ac > 0$) and so the system is considered hyperbolic.

Comment: Thank you, Mattos, this explains a bit more! However, I am still in doubt, because, for instance, at page of pdepe from MATLAB, I saw: "pdepe requires at least one parabolic equation in the system. In other words, at least one equation in the system must include a time derivative"... How this can be the same thing (time derivative and parabolicity...)...? Many thanks!

Comment: You're misunderstanding the context in which both statements are being made. I think you need to re-read both LeVeques book and the pdepe page.

Comment: @mattos, now I understand! All first order PDE is hyperbolic. About system,  https://anhngq.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/classification-of-a-system-of-n-first-order-pdes/. Many thanks.